# Debugging Angular 2 in Visual Studio Slow with Webpack

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, angular, visual-studio-2015, webpack, task-runner-explorer

I am running Visual Studio 2015 Update 3, ASP.Net MVC 4.6.1, Angular 2.4.6, Webpack 2.2.1 and the webpack Task Runner Explorer extension.  If I run Visual Studio without debugging it all works fine but if I try to run Visual Studio in debug mode it takes a couple minutes for it to load up with webpage.  Looking in Visual Studio it's trying to load up the source maps for Angular and each one is taking a couple seconds.

It seems like the problem is because the Task Runner Explorer plugin is running the command: `webpack -d --watch --color`, which is telling it to always generate source maps for everything.  It doesn't look like there is a way to change the plugin to not run the "-d" switch.  In my config file, I have it configured to only generate source maps for my code.  But it seems like the command line always overwrites what in the config file.

Has anyone figure fix this?

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
"compileOnSave": true,
"compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "lib": [ "es2015", "dom" ],
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true
  }
}
```

**webpack.dev.js**

```
var webpackMerge = require('webpack-merge');
var webpack = require('webpack');
var commonConfig = require('./webpack.common.js');

module.exports = webpackMerge(commonConfig, {

    output: {
        path: '\dist',
        publicPath: 'http://localhost:8080/',
        filename: '[name].js',
        sourceMapFilename: '[name].js.map',
        chunkFilename: '[id].chunk.js'
    },

    plugins: [
        new webpack.SourceMapDevToolPlugin({
            test: [/\.js$/, /\.ts$/],
            columns: false,
            filename: '[file].map',
            exclude: ['vendor.js', 'polyfills'],
            lineToLine: false,
            module: true,
            append: '\n//# sourceMappingURL=[url]'
        })
    ],

    devServer: {
        historyApiFallback: true,
        stats: 'minimal'
    }
});
```

**webpack.common.js**

```
"use strict";

var webpack = require('webpack');
var helpers = require('./helpers.js');
var path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        app: "./app/main.ts",
        vendor: "./app/config/vendor.ts",
        polyfills: "./app/config/polyfills.ts"
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.ts', '.js']
    },
    devServer: {
        contentBase: ".",
        host: "localhost",
        port: 9000
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
        {
            test: /\.ts$/,
            loaders: ['awesome-typescript-loader',
                'angular2-template-loader',
                'tslint-loader']
        },
        {
            test: /\.html$/,
            loader: 'raw-loader'
        },
        {
            test: /\.css$/,
            include: helpers.root('app'),
            loaders: 'style-loader!css-loader'
        },
        {
            test: /\.js$/,
            use: ["source-map-loader"], /*strips off extra # sourceMappingURL= which were in node_modules*/
            enforce: "pre",
            exclude: [
              // these packages have problems with their sourcemaps
              path.resolve('./node_modules/ng2-interceptors')
            ]
        }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        // Workaround for angular/angular#11580
        new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(
        // The (\\|\/) piece accounts for path separators in *nix and Windows
        /angular(\\|\/)core(\\|\/)(esm(\\|\/)src|src)(\\|\/)linker/,
        helpers.root('./'), // location of your src
        {} // a map of your routes
        ),
        new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
            name: ['app', 'vendor', 'polyfills']
        })
    ]

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem ended up being that there were so many source maps caused from all the Vendor and Polyfill files that VS was taking so long to load.  Once I told it to no longer generate the source maps for those it started going a lot faster.

Comment: how you did it can you explain please , i m stuck because of this issue